# Toggle going to sleep when laptop lid closes?

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3, laptop

I'm running Fedora 15 Gnome on a laptop. I can't seem to find an option to toggle if the laptop goes to sleep when the lid closes. There are certain times where I want to put the laptop away or close it but still have it do some crunching on some long running task

Is there a place to toggle this option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GNOME: disable sleep on lid close](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307497/gnome-disable-sleep-on-lid-close)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gnome Tweak Tool](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeTweakTool) allows you to change that.

Comment: Found the option under the Shell menu. Thanks!

Comment: In 2023 this link redirects to the "Tweaks" app which does not feature this setting

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, just run the command as superuser. 
For GNOME, this is now handled by systemd in Fedora 18+.

As root, edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`. You're looking for the definition for HandleLidSwitch, it may be commented out.

Modified Command : `sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf`
 You could also change dir to the folder be for running the code.

```
$ cd /etc/systemd
$ sudo gedit logind.conf
```

The default is: HandleLidSwitch=suspend

You can set it to ignore, poweroff, reboot, halt, suspend, hibernate, hybrid-sleep, lock or kexec. Since your laptop screen is broken, you just want to set it to ignore, so add this to `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

HandleLidSwitch=ignore

Then, run systemctl restart systemd-logind, or simply reboot for it to take effect.
From : [Preventing lid close suspension](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/27808/preventing-lid-close-suspension/)

Uncomment by deleting the # by the command.  Then change suspend to ignore.