# GNOME: disable sleep on lid close

Tags: gnome, suspend, laptop

Is it possible to stop my laptop going to sleep when I close the lid?

GNOME 3.20, Fedora 24.

---

My laptop does not reliably wake from sleep.  (It happens to be a hardware issue... I think I basically killed it while trying to replace a wifi card.  But I want to keep using it for a while longer).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Install GNOME Tweak Tool and go to the Power section.  There's an option to disable the automatic suspend on lid close.

### Option details

I compared `dconf` before and after to find the option, but it turns out that's not how it's implemented.  Instead, Tweak Tool creates `~/.config/autostart/ignore-lid-switch-tweak.desktop`.  The autostart is a script which effectively runs `systemd-inhibit --what=handle-lid-switch`.  So we can see the lid close action is handled purely by systemd-logind.

### Alternative route

An alternative would be to edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to include:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

This would work *all* the time, not just when your user is logged in.

Comment: Also described in the gnome [on-line help](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/power-closelid.html.en)

Comment: Lol.  It comes up in search results (8th down)... but I was searching "disable" instead of "stop".  In that case Google shows the snippet "When you close the lid of your laptop, your computer will suspend in order to save power", and _nothing else_.  I suspect I saw that, but I didn't think it was a promising avenue of investigation!  I mainly posted this question to get an answer into the Google results.  At least that's worked :).  https://www.google.com/search?q=gnome+stop+lid+close+suspend

Comment: Editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` instead of using GNOME Tweak Tool may be better because it works even when GNOME is not running, for example when working at the console.

Comment: Thanks for that. The autostart has changed since you wrote this answer. It is now: /usr/lib/gnome-tweak-tool/gnome-tweak-tool-lid-inhibitor

Comment: This causes a strange behavior on Ubuntu 18.04: it logs out periodically. Sort of like a delayed login loop!

Comment: @Ash thanks for the report, if you want to talk about collecting more information on that, it would probably work best elsewhere e.g. a separate question on this site, or a report on the Ubuntu bug tracker.

Comment: I needed to edit `logind.con` because I work with the laptop closed on an external monitor. It would go to sleep between my initial login and Gnome coming up.

Comment: @jocull Hi, that's an excellent point, but in *theory* it should already be handled. "If the system is inserted in a docking station, or if more than one display is connected, the action specified by HandleLidSwitchDocked= occurs; if the system is on external power the action (if any) specified by HandleLidSwitchExternalPower= occurs; otherwise the HandleLidSwitch= action occurs." HandleLidSwitchDocked= defaults to "ignore". Maybe you have a different version of systemd, or a bug in systemd, or your hardware/drivers don't provide the information in the right way for systemd.

Comment: @sourcejedi The problem may be that I don't have it in a docking station - it just has a monitor and keyboard/mouse plugged in :)

Comment: @jocull *or if more than one display is connected*. I haven't tried this recently, but I think I've seen it work correctly.  Intel graphics.

Comment: @sourcejedi I've got nvidia graphics -- which may be a big part of the problem :)

Comment: Note that in my case Tweaks (for GNOME 33) created the autostart entry which starts ` /usr/libexec/gnome-tweak-tool-lid-inhibitor`, which is a small Python script which does things I actually do not really understand. But it seems to also check the setting state etc. And checking `systemd-inhibit --list` I also see it basically works the same by adding an inhibitor to systemd.

Comment: It sounds like this feature of gnome-tweaks (the "Suspend when lid closed" option) [was removed](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/-/commit/782c881ee8c46a3170d192a47b9070514adbafb2) as it was considered out-of-scope for gnome-tweaks. It [has been suggested](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/1223) that this feature ought to be implemented in Gnome Settings proper, instead of Tweaks, but that hasn't happened yet.

So, it seems that as of Gnome 45 or so, **neither Tweaks nor Settings still has an option to prevent systemd from suspending on lid switch**.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Note, I'm pretty sure "gsettings" does not refer to the GNOME Settings app here. Instead, it basically means `dconf`. The executable name for Settings is `gnome-control-center`, not gsettings.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, the inhibitor routes didn't seem to work as advertised for me on openSUSE Tumbleweed (42.1) using GNOME. But, I had success with Systemd masking:

```
systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target
```

To undo the mask, you can use `unmask`:

```
systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target
```

Comment: [A serverfault answer](http://serverfault.com/a/819693/50236) pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Nothing worked but this!!

Answer (score 6):

I had solved this issue once before, but apparently recent versions of Fedora (so far from `Fedora` `28` to `33`, inclusive), require two entries now, whereas before only one was required. So:

```
user$ sudo vi /etc/systemd/logind.conf

HandleLidSwitch=ignore        <---- Set both of these
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore  <---- to ignore lid events.

user$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

**EDIT**: As mentioned by commenters below, you might want to just reboot after making the edits.

Comment: Thanks! It would be safer to reboot though. If you restart logind on a default Fedora system, your graphical X session(s) will die (same with any Wayland compositor that I know about).

Comment: This worked great for me! But I would suggest just rebooting also. When I restarted systemd it got weird and I had to kill the machine anyway.

Answer (score 4):

As [NYCeyes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/103956/nyceyes) says in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/460405/229223, one line is not the complete solution.

My configuration in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf.d/local.conf` is:

```
HandleLidSwitch=lock
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=lock
```

- Lines 1 & 3 locks the screen when the laptop is mobile or simply charging, similar to tapping the power button on my phone - make secure.
- Line 2 is to handle plugging in to my docking station (USB-C device with DisplayPort connectors) and lets me close the lid without the laptop assuming I've stopped working, when I'm actually just getting started.

The [logind.conf man](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html) page from systemd is actually very informative.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the answer and links. I found the [logind.conf docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html#) interesting. In particular, 

> `LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=` defaults to "yes". This means that when `systemd-logind` is handling events by itself (no low level inhibitor locks are taken by another application), the lid switch does not respect suspend blockers by default, but the power and sleep keys do.

Answer (score 3):

more recent versions of [systemd-logind](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html#HandlePowerKey=) support a new flag to specify the handling of lid-close on external power

```
$ /etc/systemd/logind.conf
HandleLidSwitch=suspend                # suspend when on battery
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore    # inhibit suspend when on AC 
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore           # inhibit suspend when on external monitor

$> reboot
   ↓or↑
$> sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind  # will kill current X/Wayland session
```