# how can I keep my laptop connected to the internet even when it's asleep (or even closed)?

Tags: sshd, suspend, laptop

So I've seen from [other answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307497/gnome-disable-sleep-on-lid-close/307498#307498) that it's possible to make my laptop stay on when closed. I could also make it not go to sleep in a timer, so then it would just be on all the time.

What I'm trying to do is make it so I can ssh into my laptop at any time. I think it would be a bit wasteful to leave it on continuously, so I'm wondering if there's a way that I could have it mostly suspended but still connected to the internet, so it could wake back up when I try to make a connection.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I'm running openSSH-server on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. To maintain your connection, it needs to be "on."

However, there are other solutions. There's a concept of "[Wake on LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_on_lan)" where you can send a special packet that the Ethernet card *is* able to look for when it's in an extremely low-powered state. So you can set up something on your home router that sends a WoL packet when certain conditions are met, *e.g.* you try to connect to a certain port. Or you could have another "more intelligent" device on your network (like a Raspberry Pi) accept a connection of some kind first and then send the WoL packet out.

PS. I'm not sure if WiFi supports WoL; never had to look into it.

Comment: It is possible, this is how smartphones and tablets work, and this feature is implemented in lots of Windows laptops: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby